# Zurb Foundation Top Nav bar having multiple back buttons

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I'm creating a whole website using Java / JSP, but also using zurb foundation.

Now I know that you have to call $(document).foundation(); to make foundation work, but because I'm using ajax to switch between screens (does not have that flash effect of that white screen when switching between pages) when I open my home page it executes that method ($(document).foundation();) and everything looks fine.

The problem comes in with the Top Nav bar that I have. If it goes over to the mobile version, you get that Menu button on the right hand side, and switching there between sub categories, shows a "Back" button to go back to the parent category.

The problem begins when I open my next page (using ajax), it now has components on there namely  components. These in fact looks way better on foundation than the normal standard html ones. When I execute $(document).foundation(); again, the  components goes into the foundation styled components but now with the top nav bar, there are 2 back buttons and that messes around with the functionality of the back button as well i.e. breaks it. When I go to the screen again, it adds another back button and so on.

Is there someway to revert the foundation() method, and then call it again to refresh it?

This is my Top Nav bar.

```
<div class='fixed contain-to-grid' style='height:67px;'>
<div class='large-12 columns' id='topNav'>
<nav class='top-bar'>
<ul class='title-area'>
<!-- Title Area -->
<li class='name'>
<h1><a href='#'><img src='img/logoLeft.png' style="width:181px;" id='logo'/></a></h1>
</li>
<!-- Remove the class 'menu-icon' to get rid of menu icon. Take out 'Menu' to just have    icon alone -->
<li class='toggle-topbar menu-icon'><a href='#'><span>Menu</span></a></li>
</ul>

<section class='top-bar-section'>
<ul class="left">
<li class="divider" id='div1' style='display:none;'></li>
<li class="has-dropdown" id='nonFinNav' style='display:none;'><a href="#">Non-Financial</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><label>Heading 1</label></li>
<li><a href="#">Cat 1</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Cat 2</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Cat 3</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#" id='leaveMain'>Cat 4</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><label>Leave</label></li>
<li><a href="#" id="leaveApplicationLink">SubCat 1</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">SubCat 2</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">SubCat 3</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="divider" id='div2' style='display:none;'></li>
<li class="has-dropdown" id='FinNav' style='display:none;'><a href="#" style='margin-   right:29px;'>Financial</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><label>Heading 2</label></li>
<li><a href="#">Cat 1</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Cat 2</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Cat 3</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Cat 4</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="divider" id='div3' style='display:none;'></li>
</ul>
<!-- Right Nav Section -->
<ul class='right'>
<li><a id='logOffButton' style='display:none;'>Log Off</a></li>
<li class='divider'></li>
<li><a id='helpButton'>Help</a></li>
<li class='divider'></li>
</ul>
</section>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

If you need any more info, please ask and I will respond.

Thanks.

Comment: tl;dr. Mind making a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having the same issue. I couldn't find a solution through foundation, but I did come up with something that's suitable for my purposes.

Firstly, instead of simply doing $(document).foundation(), I execute

```
$(document).foundation({topbar : {custom_back_text: false }});
```

This makes it so that the "back" button is now named after its previous menu. So, each back button title should be unique. It's important that they are unique. Now, I have a script that removes all duplicate menu items, based on their link text. I have it set to trigger each time someone clicks on a menu item with sub-items (foundation gives these a class of 'has-dropdown not-click'). This way the script only runs when it's truly needed.

```
function (){
    var uniqueBackButtons = [];
    $.each($('.back'), function(){
        if(uniqueBackButtons.indexOf(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data) == -1){
            uniqueBackButtons.push(this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data);
        }
        else{
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I was having weird top nav dropdown box behaviour issues. Adding the class 'not-click' with 'has-dropdown' solved my issue.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue.

I think the reason why I do have multiple "back" button is because of multiple declaration of this code:

```
 $(document).foundation();
```

Notice that I have embedded this

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

that also contains that script. ***It works to me.*** I put all my scripts on js/app.js